# Binding list of objects with Knockoutjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js, webforms, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to bind data to ASP.NET Webforms Application using [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com) and [Knockout Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

**HTML**

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function bindModel(data) {
        var viewModel;
        viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        console.log(viewModel);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "TestPage.aspx/GetItems",
            data: {},
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (result) {
                bindModel(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
...
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Item">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Id">
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: Name">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**C#**

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Item> GetItems()
{
    List<Item> itemlist = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, Name = "Item1", Description = "Item 1 Description"},
            new Item {Id = 2, Name = "Item2", Description = "Item 2 Description"}
        };

    return itemlist;
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

**JSON Response**

```
{"d":[{"__type":"KnockoutWebFormsTest.Item","Id":1,"Name":"Item1","Description":"Item 1 Description"},{"__type":"KnockoutWebFormsTest.Item","Id":2,"Name":"Item2","Description":"Item 2 Description"}]}
```

But this gives an error,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: foreach: Item
Message: Item is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here, How to fix this?

---

### EDIT :

If I call `bindModel` directly with data, like

```
bindModel({ "d": [{ "__type": "KnockoutWebFormsTest.Item", "Id": 21, "Name": "Item1", "Description": "Item 1 Description" }, { "__type": "KnockoutWebFormsTest.Item", "Id": 2, "Name": "Item2", "Description": "Item 2 Description"}] });
```

and change `data-bind="foreach: Item"` to `data-bind="foreach: d"` (As suggested by david.s)

It works fine... But if I pass JSON result directly to bindModel it gives the error

```
d is not defined
```

Any idea how to fix this Issue?

Comment: sorry i moved it from a comment to a suggested answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your JSON response `{"d":[ ... ]}` I can see that the array is called `d`. So your binding should be `foreach: d`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but you are not passing the array to be bound. 
You are passing the json object. `{d:[{foo:bar},{foo:bar},]}`

You could change this line `bindModel(result);`
 to `bindModel(result.d);` in order to access the array that "d" contains.

I have created a JSBin.. 
http://jsbin.com/uxikew/2/edit

The ajax call has been removed but you get the point.

Comment: What do you mean by "you are not passing the array to be bound"?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the answers and help...

Finally Managed to get it working,

by changing `data-bind="foreach: Item"` to `data-bind="foreach: d"` (as sugested by david.s)

and `viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);` to `viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);`

Comment: if you got to the answer from someones post then they should get the accepted answer.