# Using server side object type in Knockout foreach Databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, knockout.js

I get this JSON response from ASP.NET web method

> {"d":[{"__type":"KnockoutWebFormsTest.Item","Id":1,"Name":"Item1","Description":"Item
>   1
>   Description"},{"__type":"KnockoutWebFormsTest.Item","Id":2,"Name":"Item2","Description":"Item
>   2 Description"}]}

Then using **KnockoutJS** I can bind data with this code,

**Javascript**:

```
function bindModel(data) {
    var viewModel;
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  }
```

**HTML**:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: d">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This uses object type of `d` in `foreach` loop, But now what I need to use my server object type `Item` in foreach loop like,

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Item">
```

How can I achieve this?

Note : this is related to my previous question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008743/binding-list-of-objects-with-knockoutjs/18015002#18015002)

---

**EDIT 1 :**

**Server Side Code (C#)**

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Item> GetItems()
{
    List<Item> itemlist = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item {Id = 1, Name = "Item1", Description = "Item 1 Description"},
        new Item {Id = 2, Name = "Item2", Description = "Item 2 Description"}
    };

    return itemlist;
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2 :**

From this Javascript code

```
var jsonObject;
jsonObject = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
console.log(data);
console.log(jsonObject);
console.log(jsonObject.d);
```

I get

**data**

> {"d":[{"__type":"KnockoutWebFormsTest.Item","Id":1,"Name":"Item1","Description":"Item 1
>   Description"},{"__type":"KnockoutWebFormsTest.Item","Id":2,"Name":"Item2","Description":"Item 2 Description"}]}

**jsonObject**

```
>Object {d: function, __ko_mapping__: Object}
 >__ko_mapping__: Object
 >d: Object[0]
 >__proto__: Object
```

**jsonObject.d**

> []

Comment: Can you show us how you're serializing this to JSON on the server side?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Added C# Code as a Edit, Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the default behaviour from what I've seen.. since this is a `WebMethod` that returns `JSON` - from .NET 3.5 onwards, there was a breaking change to add a `d` property on payloads returned.

See here: http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

Specifically:

`So the wrapping of the "d" parameter prevents direct execution of the string as script. No Object or Array constructor worries.`.

What you can do, is assign this somewhere else, like so:

```
var jsonObject;
jsonObject = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
var viewModel = { Item: jsonObject.d };
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This will allow you to set the binding:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Item">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but then I get this error: `Item is not defined`. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should change your data and build it like this:

```
Data = [d:[{
Id: "1",
Name: "Saeed",
LastName: "SWD",
Description: "ok",
Items:[{ Id: "1", Description: "ok"},
       { Id: "1", Description: "ok"}]
}]];
```

Then you would be able to access Items as below:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: d">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
```